# About definition of Fuchsian group derived from a quaternion algebra

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, quaternions

In Katok's book, we have a defintion as following:

> If $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of finite index of some
>   $\Gamma(A,\mathcal{O})$, then we call $\Gamma$ a Fuchsian group
>   derived from a quaternion algebra $A$.

We know that subgroup of a Fuchsian group is also a Fuchsian group. So, what is the motivation of "subgroup of finite index" in that definition?

Comment: I think two questions are distinct. $\Gamma(A,\mathcal{O})=\rho(\mathcal{O}^1)/ \{\pm{Id}\}$ where $\mathcal{O}^1=\{x\in \mathcal{O}|{Nrd}(x)=1\}$ and $\rho :\left ( \frac{a,b}{\mathbb{Q}} \right )\rightarrow M(2,\mathbb{R})$,$x\mapsto g_x=\begin{bmatrix}
x_0+x_1\sqrt{a} &x_2+x_3\sqrt{a} \\ 
 b(x_2-x_3\sqrt{a})&x_0-x_1\sqrt{a} 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: Then the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_Fuchsian_group) definition is the right one. It does not mention "finite index", except for *arithmetic* Fuchsian group", i.e., because the arithmeticity of such subgroups follows from the fact that they are finite-index in an arithmetic group.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Finite index is what we need for $\mathcal{H}^* \setminus \Gamma$ being a compact Riemann surface ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, otherwise $\Gamma$ only has finite covolume.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can you show me a counter-example?

Comment: There are counterexamples already for discrete subgroups $\Gamma$ of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243508/examples-of-discrete-subgroups-of-psl-2-mathbfr-with-finite-covolume-and-w).

Comment: Perhaps the counterexample you want is just any infinite cyclic subgroup $C < \Gamma(A,\mathcal{O})$. Note that since $C$ has infinite index, it is not cocompact. It also does not have finite covolume because it has no cusps.